# Websockets in Firefox not working with several HTTPS pages

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, ssl, websocket

I have a websocket client-server application. Here's client's simplified code:

```
const HOST = "wss://localhost:8000";

const SUB_PROTOCOL= "sub-protocol"; 

var websocket = new WebSocket(HOST, SUB_PROTOCOL);

websocket.onopen  = function(evt)   { ... };
websocket.onclose = function(evt)   { ... };
websocket.onerror = function(evt)   { ... };
websocket.onmessage = function(evt) { ... };
```

And here's server:

```
const PORT = 8000;
const SUBPROTOCOL = 'sub-protocol';

var WebSocketServer = require('websocket').server;

var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

// Private key and certification (self-signed for now) 
var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('cert/server.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('cert/server.crt')
};

var server = https.createServer(options, function(request, response) {
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Received HTTP(S) request for ' + request.url);
    response.writeHead(404);
    response.end();
}); 

// bind server object to listen to PORT number
server.listen(PORT, function() {
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Server is listening on port ' + PORT);
});

wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
    httpServer: server,
    // You should not use autoAcceptConnections for production
    // applications, as it defeats all standard cross-origin protection
    // facilities built into the protocol and the browser.  You should
    // *always* verify the connection's origin and decide whether or not
    // to accept it.
    autoAcceptConnections: false
});


function originIsAllowed(origin) {
  // put logic here to detect whether the specified origin is allowed.
  return true;
}

// If autoAcceptConnections is set to false, a request event will be emitted
// by the server whenever a new WebSocket request is made
wsServer.on('request', function(request) {

    if (!originIsAllowed(request.origin)) {
      // Make sure we only accept requests from an allowed origin
      request.reject();
      console.log((new Date()) + ' Connection from origin ' + request.origin + ' rejected.');
      return;
    }

    // accepts connection and return socket for this connection
    var connection = request.accept(SUB_PROTOCOL, request.origin);

    console.log((new Date()) + ' Connection accepted.');

    // when message is received
    connection.on('message', function(message) {

        // echo
        connection.send(connection, message.utf8Data);

    });


    connection.on('close', function(reasonCode, description) {
        console.log((new Date()) + ' Peer ' + connection.remoteAddress + ' disconnected.');
    });

});
```

Both client and server works as expected even with some HTTPS pages (tested on Twitter, mail.ru,). But for some reason doesn't for example with Facebook or GitHub.

In JavaScript console I get this:

`Exception { message: "", result: 2153644038, name: "", filename: "", lineNumber: 0, columnNumber: 0, inner: null, data: null }`

Then huge stack trace follows: pasted it [here](http://pastebin.com/JieadgV1)

and at the end:

`Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at wss://localhost:8000/ ("connect-src https://github.com:443 https://ghconduit.com:25035 https://live.github.com:443 https://uploads.github.com:443 https://s3.amazonaws.com:443").`

I don't see how does these page differ from pages, which works. I'd also like to point out, that these pages works in Chrome.

(tested in Firefox 31)

Answer (score 1):

The pages where the WebSocket connection fails have a `Content-Security-Policy` header with the `connect-src` directive set to only allow connections to a set of whitelisted domains.  This means that all connections from that page to any non-whitelisted domain will fail.

Its not clear how you're running this code.  It seems possible that Chrome allows extensions to bypass that header restriction while Firefox does not, or something to that effect.

Comment: Yes, client's code is a part of library running as content script in firefox/chrome plugin. So I guess there's nothing to do with this? If I could break content-security-policy, there would be no reason to have it, right.

Luckily, this is just an experimental method, so if it's dead-end, I can shut it, before it's not too late.

Comment: @dakov I can't find a way to make Firefox act like Chrome with respect to the Content-Security-Policy header and plugins.  Looks like a dead end.